# Getting error in layout.tsx file while setting up sitecore headless - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')

Tags: jss

Getting Error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')` while Setting Up `Sitecore Headless in Sitecore 10.3`

Please find the attached screenshot for reference

[image]

I have diligently followed all the steps outlined in the blog https://www.getfishtank.com/blog/how-to-setup-xm-cloud-sitecore-10-sxa-headless-and-nextjs.

However, I am still encountering this error at the end of the setup process.

Could anyone offer insights or suggestions to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You might not have the field "pageTitle" field defined in your page template. Please try and change the line to

```
fields?.pageTitle?.value?.toString()
```

Comment: I have previously attempted to include a similar conditional code. After modifying the line as per your suggestion, the page appears with 2 links.
Additionally, when accessing the page through the Experience Editor, I am unable to access the toolbox, and placeholders are also not visible.

Comment: Can you check the console errors? Seems like both the issues are unrelated

Answer (score 0):

Always check the fields in the layout service before accessing them in your frontend code.

You can either open the layout service through the URL `/sitecore/api/layout/render/jss?item=[path]&sc_lang=[language]&sc_apikey=[key]`

or use the browser console `window.__JSS_STATE__`.

Don’t forget to implement null checks on your fields to prevent code breaks.